# Concise way to compare a variable against multiple values

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been trying to understand if it is possible to use an if statement similar to the likes of what I have demonstrated here below. It is my understand that it is not?

```
for i in range(10):
  if i == (3 or 5) or math.sqrt(i) == (3 or 5):
    numbers.append(i)
```

With this block of code I only get the numbers `3` & `9`, while I should be getting `3, 5, 9`. Is there another way of doing so without listing the code below?

```
for i in range(10):
  if i == 3 or i == 5 or math.sqrt(i) == 3 or math.sqrt(i) == 5:
    numbers.append(i)
```

Comment: You could do it as `if i in [3, 5]` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `in` operator:

```
for i in range(10):
  if i in (3, 5) or math.sqrt(i) in (3, 5):
    numbers.append(i)
```

or in case you expect each of the calculations to be in the same group of results, you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
results = [1, 2, ..., too long list for single line]
expected = (3, 5)

if any([result in expected for result in results]):
    print("Found!")
```

Just a minor nitpick, `sqrt` will most likely return a `float` sooner or later and this approach will be silly in the future, therefore [`math.isclose()` or others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595425/5994041) will help you not to encounter float "bugs" such as:

```
2.99999999999999 in (3, 5)  # False
```

which will cause your condition to fail.

Answer (score 4):

```
if i == (3 or 5) or math.sqrt(i) == (3 or 5):
```

is equivalent to

```
if i == 3 or math.sqrt(i) == 3:
```

leading to 3 and 9 as results.
This because `3 or 5` is evaluated as 3 by being 3 the first non-zero number (nonzero numbers are considered True). For instance, `0 or 5` would be evaluated as 5.

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is instead of using "==" here, that you use "in". Here is that code:

```
for i in range(10):
  if i in [3,5] or math.sqrt(i) in [3,5]:
    numbers.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension like this.

```
import math as mt
a=list(range(10))
filtered_list=[x for x in a if x in [3,5] or mt.sqrt(x) in [3,5]]
print(filtered_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one:

```
if i in (3,5) or math.sqrt(i) in (3,5):
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.